# "Yum update" how to delete ghost package?

Tags: yum, rpm

**How do I delete package insign-3.43.3-1 from the "database" for `yum update`?**

* `yum update insign` shows me package 3.43.3-1.

* `yum update` would fail because I already removed the 3.43...rpm file

* `rpm -qa | grep insign` does not! show me the package 3.43.3!

* `yum list insign` shows me package 3.43.3

* `sudo rpm -e insign-3.43.3-1.el7.x86_64` -> error: package insign-3.43.3-1.el7.x86_64 is not installed

* `sudo yum erase insign-3.43.3-1.el7.x86_64` -> No Match for argument

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/624979/rpm-based-linux-how-can-i-remove-a-locally-installed-package

Comment: Thank you. See second screenshot in my message. 
-> I tried both 
```sudo rpm -e insign-3.43.3-1.el7.x86_64``` and 
```sudo yum erase insign-3.43.3-1.el7.x86_64```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that after deleting package XY.rpm the *Repository List* needs to be *updated* and Yum needs to be *cleaned*

```
cd /directory-of-repository-packages
sudo -S createrepo .
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum --showduplicates list package-xy
```